# How to stop showing the webpage after entering wrong answers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one webpage ,when loading the page it asks some questions if all the questions are correct only then it displays the body part otherwise the question will not allow next question or it should not displays the body part , please help me to fix this issue...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Special-Wishes </title>
<script>
let q1=prompt("what is your name...?");    //if the q1 answer is wrong it should not display the body content
if(q1 == "John" || "JOHN" ){
    let q2=prompt("what's your nick name...?"); 
      if(q2=="blabla"){
         alert("welcome to the page"); 
      }
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My body section</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you like the body to be "visible" or "loaded"? Because I can give you a quick answer if you just want it to be visible, otherwise I think you'll have to use an AJAX-like request.

Comment: the answers are correct means it should visible the page otherwise the question remains same it will not allow another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is still asking the next question is due to your `if` statement logic
`if(q1 == "John" || "JOHN" )` should be `if(q1 == "John" || q1 == "JOHN" )`

An even easier way of doing this would be `if(q1.toUpperCase() == "JOHN")`

In order to not display the body, you want to either remove it, or make it hidden. This can be done in a `else` block after your `if` statement

Remove: `document.body.remove();`
Hide: `document.body.style.display = "none";`

Comment: an hidden body will be easily discovered with browser dev tools...

Comment: if i wrong enter wrong answer also it's displaying the page

Comment: @LelioFaieta that is why i also gave the solution to flat out remove the body

Comment: @saitarun did you add an else block? It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/g1prj38x/

Comment: in my browser if i enter wrong answers also it's showing the webpage, but in your case is working

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.body.style.display = "none"` when condition not matched

```js
let q1 = prompt("what is your name...?"); //if the q1 answer is wrong it should not display the body content
if (q1 == "John") {
  let q2 = prompt("what's your nick name...?");
  if (q2 == "blabla") {
    alert("welcome to the page");
  } else {
    document.body.style.display = "none"
  }
} else {
  document.body.style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>My body section</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: an hidden body will be easily discovered with browser dev tools...

Comment: Then removing body tag will be the best shot for OP . If wanted to hide from inspector too @LelioFaieta

Comment: even if it's wrong answer also it's showing the body section

Comment: When I can't find that . When you don't enter blabla or John . It will hide body tag @saitarun